# Как извлечь данные из HTML строки HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, linq

Получаю строку такого типа

```
<div class="popup">
<div class="popup-top"></div>
<div class="popup-middle">
<div>Тип обложки: обл - мягкий переплет (крепление скрепкой или клеем)</div>
<div>Иллюстрации: Черно-белые + цветные</div>
</div>
<div class="popup-bottom">
</div></div>
```

Мне нужно получить вот это `Черно-белые + цветные`. 
причем вот это `<div>Иллюстрации: Черно-белые + цветные</div>`, может и отсутствовать или порядок, может быть другой. Единственный ориентир это слово `Иллюстрации:`.

Пробовал сделать вот так

```
 string illustration = `htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='popup']").Where(x=>x.InnerText.Contains("Иллюстрации:")).Select(s=>s.InnerText).FirstOrDefault();`
```

Все ок, но он выбирает весь текст

```
"Тип обложки: 7Бц - твердая, целлофанированная (или лакированная)Иллюстрации: Цветные"
```

,а мне нужен только `Цветные`, или пусть просто возьмет содержимое div? вот так

```
Иллюстрации: Черно-белые + цветные, дальше закрепленность слово не проблема.
```

Comment: String[] arr = div_str.Split(':');
string need_value = arr[arr.count - 1]; Где div_str - содержит выбранный весь текст.

Comment: А если изменить на `htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div").Where(x=>x.InnerText.Contains("Иллюстрации:")).Select(s=>s.InnerText).LastOrDefault();`?

Comment: @SurfinBird возвращает null(

Comment: @shatoidil, странно, только что проверил, [вроде работает](http://i.imgur.com/bhjUsHZ.png).

Comment: "<div class=\"popup\"><div class=\"popup-top\"></div><div class=\"popup-middle\"><div>Тип обложки: обл - мягкий переплет (крепление скрепкой или клеем)</div><div>Иллюстрации: Цветные</div></div><div class=\"popup-bottom\"></div></div>"  Вот с этим попробуйте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что у вас находится первый узел `div` с классом `popup` и извлекается его содержимое. А оно берётся со всеми вложенными подузлами.

Исправьте ваше xpath-выражение следующим образом:

```
"//div[@class='popup']/*/div"
```

и будет извлекаться то, что нужно.

Так как у вас берутся данные только из одного узла - первого, то можно вместо `SelectNodes` использовать метод `SelectSingleNode`. А также предлагаю использовать мощь xpath:

```
string illustration = htmlDocument.DocumentNode
    .SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='popup']/*/div[contains(.,'Иллюстрации:')]")
    .InnerText;
```

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему следующим образом

```
  var illustration = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[contains(text(), 'Иллюстрации:')]").InnerText;
```

То есть выборка идет по тексту

Comment: Эх, я чуть опоздал. Одобряю!

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Но Вы хорошо объяснили!